# Quitar $ y R$ en un string

Tags: javascript, regex

Intento eliminar `$` y `R$` de un string.

Lo que he intentado es

```
$scope.TotalOwed.replace(/\$\R$/g, '');
```

pero no me funcionó.

Comment: A ver si entendi. Quieres eliminar esas letras y tambien quieres mostrar el resultado con el mismo modelo en la vista?

Comment: hola, @Einer lo que pasa es que me pasan precios por ejemplo como $253, R$7885, entonces cuando se van a mostrar en un pdf, esos caracteres deben de desaparecer, y lo único que debo mostrar es el numero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcciones:

- `$` es un [caracter especial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Utilizando_caracteres_especiales) en regex (que coincide con el fin del texto). Para que coincida con el caracter literal hay que [escaparlo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-backslash) como `\$`.
- `R` no es un caracter especial. No hace falta escaparlo. Cualquier grupo de caracteres literales coincide con ese texto.
- Para poner 2 opciones dentro del patrón se usa un `|`, que indica [alternancia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or).
  El regex `/\$|R\$/g` funcionaría.
- Sin embargo, es más sencillo usar un [cuantificador](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark). Un `?` repite a la construcción anterior 0 o 1 vez. Es decir, la hace opcional. Nos sirve para la `R`.

Solución:

```
texto.replace(/R?\$/g, '');
```

- Una `"R"` opcional y un signo `"$"`.
- El modificador `/g` hace que reemplace todas las ocurrencias, y no sólo la primera.

Demo:

```js
var texto = document.getElementById('texto'),
    resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');


function eliminarMoneda(){
    resultado.innerText = texto.value.replace(/R?\$/g, '');
}
eliminarMoneda();

texto.addEventListener('input', eliminarMoneda);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto" style="width:100%"
       value="Reemplazamos en $123 y R$456">
<pre id="resultado">
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer esto:

```
$scope.TotalOwed.replace(/(\$|\R\$)/g, '');
```

Y si quieres guardar el valor de `$scope.TotalOwed` sin `$` ni `R$` entonces solo guárdalo en una variable:

```
var sin_$_ni_R$ = $scope.TotalOwed.replace(/(\$|\R\$)/g, '');
```

O bien:

```
$scope.TotalOwed = $scope.TotalOwed.replace(/(\$|\R\$)/g, '');
```

Espero y te sirva.

Answer (score -1):

Inténtalo de esta forma:

```
$scope.TotalOwed.replace(/(\$)|([R$])/g,'');
```

Elimina: $ y R$

Comment: Esto eliminaría todas las `"R"` del texto, `"Realmente las eliminaRía".replace(/(\$)|([R$])/g,'');`